# Long delay when my jQuery function fires due to a large amount of values in my select form elements

Tags: php, jquery

I have a `.php` page with about two hundred `select` form elements on it. The element values are being populated by a `.txt` file in the same directory using PHP:

```
<?php

$schoolselected = 'schools.txt';
$eachlines1 = file($schoolselected, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

?>
```

and

```
<select name="schoolselected001">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select School...</option>
    <option value=" " <?php if(isset($_POST['schoolselected001'])) echo "selected"; ?>></option>
       <?php foreach($eachlines1 as $lines1){
            echo "<option value='".$lines1."'>$lines1</option>";
        }?>
</select>
```

Each `select` form element have the same name but with 001 through 200.

I'm using this jQuery function to disable an `option` when selected to prevent doubling up:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('select[name*=schoolselected]').on('click', function() {
  $('option').prop('disabled', false);
  $('select[name*=schoolselected]').each(function() {
    var val = this.value;
    $('select[name*=schoolselected]').not(this).find('option').filter(function() {
      return this.value === val;
    }).prop('disabled', true);
  });
}).change();
});
</script>
```

Everything works perfectly and there was no delay when I tested with ten `values` but now with two hundred `values`, there is a 10-12 second delay each time I click any of the `select` form elements.

Are there any tweaks I can do to the existing code to remove the delay? Or maybe I'm taking the wrong approach? I looked into caching the data but had no luck finding a solution. If I disable the jQuery function there is zero delay. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Who is using 200 select dropdowns?

Comment: Its for an internal project at work. I was tired of re-adding code and additional school information to a page every time they wanted it updated. Now I can open a text file and add the school quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So many questions to what you are trying to achieve

Why 200 select dropdowns?

Why did you use 'on click' on a select? you want 'on change' event right?

your code is slow because you are iterating twice over your 200 selects

here is the working code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var lastSelectedValue = {};

$('select[name*=schoolselected]').on('change', function() {

var currentSelect = this.attributes.name.value;
var oldValue = lastSelectedValue[currentSelect];
lastSelectedValue[currentSelect] = this.value;

    $('select[name*=schoolselected]').not(this).each(function() {
        if(oldValue){
         $(this).find("option[value='"+oldValue+"']").prop('disabled', false);
        }
        $(this).find("option[value='"+lastSelectedValue[currentSelect]+"']").prop('disabled', true);
    });
    
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: The amount of dropdowns aren't creating the lag because I reduced the amount of values to about 10 and even with the 200 select dropdowns, there was no lag. It comes down to the amount of values in total. I also originally had it set to 'on change' but the page would not load. I think it was iterating every time the PHP code included each line. By changing it to on click, it allowed the page to load instantly for testing.

Comment: I tried out your code and there is no lag, but its also not disabling the values when I select anymore.

Comment: Hey Sofien. I am incorrect regarding the amount of dropdowns. I just ran a couple tests. I tried with 250 values and 10 select form elements and no lag. I tried with 200 select form elements and only ten values and the lag is very minimal, almost unnoticeable.

Comment: I made a small change can you try again?

Comment: Appreciate your help. 

Update: So that changed kind of worked. What's happening now is it disables the value/item in all the dropdown lists, but as soon as I select a different dropdown list and select a new item, it re-enables the last selected item and disables the new one I selected. I will update my original post with a couple screenshots showing what its doing now.

Comment: ok I updated my answer so you have your desired behavior

I just assumed you want the first part only as you was using this line in your original code 

  $('option').prop('disabled', false);

Comment: Works like a charm. I really appreciate your help with this. Is there any way for it to apply when the page is refreshed as well?

Comment: yes either reset all the fields on page refresh or you can do nearly the same thing I did ... after $(document).ready
1- $('select[name*=schoolselected]').each get Current Option Value 2- do another loop over all the other selects with .not(this).each and disable the option that have the value that you have on step 1

Comment: Thanks. I will try to incorporate those settings into your existing code.